Different approaches to the month of Elul
What is the basic difference in approach to the month of Elul between the Litvish and Chassidic communities? And what are the sources?

Nusach aside, is there a reason why you might think they are different?

As in everything else: Litvaks talk about sheleimus and temimus (wholeness) and emulating Hashem. The main talk of the month is self repair. Chassidim talk about deveiqus (attachment), and so in Elul spend more time (than a Litvak would) talking about Hashem "making Himself available".
